# Use process status as a boolean in a bash script

Tags: centos, services

I'm still new to linux scripting, but not so new to programming as a paradigm, so please forgive me if my question has a super obvious answer.

Background: I want to write a startup script that merely checks if a process has been started, and if it has not, to start it. More specifically, I want to check that iptables, fail2ban, asterisk, and mysqld have started properly after a reboot.

I want the script to determine the status of the given service in a true/false manner. IE I want the script to give me either true or false when it comes to the service being active or not.

I have played around with a couple of "ps -aux" and "ps -ef" options that I found on forums but they aren't really giving me the results I want, or maybe I'm just not understanding the explanation correctly.

I just want to be able to determine if a service is running in a meaningful way and use the result determine the logical flow of a startup script.

Thanks in advance for any responses, and apologies if the question is posted in the wrong place.

Comment: This is a great question to ask and you're in the right place; welcome!  However, there are several very different directions you could go, so I'm not sure how to answer.  Are you aware that most CentOS/RHEL services can be set to start on boot with `chkconfig`?  And you're aware of `service status`?  (NB: I haven't checked if the specific services you named are integrated with `chkconfig` and `service`.)  (cont'd)

Comment: Are you worried about those processing dying and want to ensure they stay running?  (In which case you might check out Configuration Management software such as [CFEngine](https://cfengine.com/learn/why-cfengine/).)  Or do you just want a quick-and-dirty hack for a one-off script not meant to be used other than on your own personal box?  (I doubt it, but it's a possibility.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some cursory testing is demonstrating that on my system, the `service` utility will return an exit code of 3 when checking on the status of a service which is not running.  Therefore, this might do the trick for you:

```
for svc in iptables fail2ban asterisk mysqld; do
    if ! service "$svc" status > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "$svc is either not running or is an indeterminate state."
    fi
done
```

Comment: This works for services that are implemented by a running process, which is the case for most of the examples mentioned here. `iptables` is a different beast: it's implemented by a one-time setup, it doesn't have a concept of “currently running”.